# cpimport in mariadb columnstore inserting empty string instead of null for varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, columnstore

Mariadb Details: 10.3.11-MariaDB

I am trying to import bunch of CSV files in a newly created table on Mariadb columnstore engine.

Steps I performed:

1)Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_raw_data`.`cpimport_test` (
col1 VARCHAR(100),
col2 VARCHAR(100),
col3 VARCHAR(100)
)  ENGINE=columnstore;
```

2)Use an existing csv file to import data

```
col1,col2,col3
AA,BB,
BB,CC,
```

3)Use cpimport to import data from a s3 file

```
ssh -i <PEM> <user>@<dburl> "aws s3 cp --quiet s3://mybucket/test.csv - | tail -n+2 | /home/mysql/mariadb/columnstore/bin/cpimport test_raw_data cpimport_test -e 5 -E \\\" -s,"
```

**Actual result:
For column 3, I have kept an empty value. When I see that in mysql workbench it is translated to empty string.**

**Expected Result:
For column 3, it should put default value as NULL.**

Documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/columnstore-bulk-data-loading/
I tried -n flag but it also keeps the value as "NULL".

Somehow I am stuck on this issue and not able to figure out what is wrong on my end. Thank you in advance.

I tried mysql workbench import wizard to see the result. I made few additional null values to see the results. When I used import wizard it was able to put values as NULL on col3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no0oB.png)

Comment: *it is translated to empty string* This is correct. See the documentation about NULL value encoding in CSV. Update your table after importing and replace empty strings with NULLs. Or add BEFORE INSERT trigger which will do this during importing.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for replying. The strange thing is it is translated to the default values for other column having the same data type so I am a bit confused why this behavior persists for the last column. I have a larger table in which blank values are translated to NULL except for the last/newly added column with same data type and default value.